# proof of Euler φ-function

Tags: number-theory

The Euler φ-function φ(n) counts the number of positive integers that
are less than or equal to n and relatively prime to n. 
give a direct proof of the following formula:
φ(n)=∑n*µ(d)/d

when µ is mobius function:
µ(1) = 1, 
µ(n) = (−1)^m, if n is the product of m distinct primes, 
µ(n) = 0, otherwise

Answer (score 0):

$\phi(n) = \sum \limits_{k\leq n,(k,n)=1} 1 = \sum \limits_{k\leq n} \sum \limits_{d |(n,k)} \mu(d) = \sum \limits_{d |n} \mu(d) \sum \limits_{d|k , k\leq n} 1 = \sum \limits_{d |n} \mu(d) [\frac{n}{d}]$

Since $d|n$ we have finally that $\phi(n) = \sum \limits_{d |n} \mu(d) \frac{n}{d}$